# Question Regarding Send_to_many function of blockchain wallet api

Tags: blockchain, wallet, blockchain.info, api

I am using send to many function of blockchain wallet api and i am facing issue.

when upto 20 transaction done then after i get error in terminal that

1538652825520 - error: ERR_PUSHTX

1538652826930 - error: ERR_PUSHTX

and until that upto 20 transactions get 1 confirmation on block i am unable to send any other transaction from that wallet and it's specific address.

i want to use sent to many function for sending unlimited transaction from one wallet to my site users bitcoin addresses when they submit payment request from their account.

kindly help me regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: Is your fee too low? See https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3/issues/105

Comment: thank you very much it was really help full for me.

Comment: but i still want to ask one question, what if fee is set to normal and still after 20 transactions it's show

1538652826930 - error: ERR_PUSHTX

Comment: This isn't really answering the question but it is a suggestion. If you're sending out that many transactions, wouldn't it be easier (and cheaper) to combine your inputs and outputs into a single transaction? Instead of spamming a bunch of smaller TX's, you could create 1 or more large TX's with many more inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to manage is the fee rate. Bitcoin core nodes will not relay transactions (or include them in blocks) below the minimum fee rate of 1000 satoshi/kB (`-minrelaytxfee`), so if you keep increasing the transaction size, but not the fee, you risk not getting relayed or even mined (`-blockmintxfee`), since miners typically maximize the fee rate in the block being mined.

Comment: But when i am adding fee in satoshi still it's taking too much time to get 1 confirmation. which is required to process further transaction from 1 address after 24 transactions are pending.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it